# UPS API throws error "Invalid Shipment content Value" for US country

Tags: api, magento2.4, ups

I am using UPS API in Magento for CANADA and USA country, if I am passing the same request parameters for Canada it works fine and gets a response as aspected, but if I pass US address in `<ShipTo>` parameter in UPS API request. it throws the error `invalid shipment contents value`

Here is UPS API **Request**. The below request is passing. It works fine for Canada address, but it does not work for the US address.

Can anyone address me what I am going to wrong below request for US address?

**Request**

```
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">    
  <AccessLicenseNumber>******</AccessLicenseNumber> 
  <UserId>*****</UserId>    
  <Password>*****</Password>    
</AccessRequest><?xml version="1.0"?>   
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">    
  <Request> 
    <TransactionReference>  
      <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext> 
      <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>    
    </TransactionReference> 
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction> 
    <RequestOption>Shoptimeintransit</RequestOption>    
  </Request>    
  <PickupType>  
          <Code>01</Code>   
          <Description>Regular Daily Pickup</Description>   
  </PickupType> 
  <Shipment>      <Shipper><ShipperNumber>****</ShipperNumber>      <Address>   
          <City>Scarborough</City>  
          <PostalCode>M1G 0A6</PostalCode>  
          <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
          <StateProvinceCode>ON</StateProvinceCode> 
      </Address>    
    </Shipper>  
    <ShipTo>    
      <Address> 
          <PostalCode>14304</PostalCode>    
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode> 
          <ResidentialAddress>02</ResidentialAddress>   
          <StateProvinceCode>NY</StateProvinceCode>      </Address> 
    </ShipTo>   
    <ShipFrom>  
      <Address> 
          <PostalCode>M1G 0A6</PostalCode>  
          <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
          <StateProvinceCode>ON</StateProvinceCode> 
      </Address>    
    </ShipFrom> 
    <DeliveryTimeInformation>   
    <PackageBillType>03</PackageBillType>   
</DeliveryTimeInformation>  
    <Package>   
      <PackagingType>   
        <Code>00</Code> 
      </PackagingType>  
      <PackageWeight>   
        <UnitOfMeasurement> 
          <Code>LBS</Code>  
        </UnitOfMeasurement>    
        <Weight>0.2</Weight>    
      </PackageWeight>  
    </Package>  
    <ShipmentTotalWeight>   
    <UnitOfMeasurement> 
        <Code>LBS</Code>    
    </UnitOfMeasurement>    
    <Weight>0.2</Weight>    
    </ShipmentTotalWeight><RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation>      </Shipment>   
    </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<RatingServiceSelectionResponse>
    <Response>
        <TransactionReference>
            <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>
            <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
        </TransactionReference>
        <ResponseStatusCode>0</ResponseStatusCode>
        <ResponseStatusDescription>Failure</ResponseStatusDescription>
        <Error>
            <ErrorSeverity>Hard</ErrorSeverity>
            <ErrorCode>111549</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Invalid Shipment Contents Value.</ErrorDescription>
        </Error>
    </Response>
</RatingServiceSelectionResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty frequent error when using this API. And I found a quite useful solution. I applied and now it's working fine on my website.

Requires to add new `<InvoiceLineTotal>` section in `<shipment>` section and `<city>` is required in `<ShipTo>` section.

Comment: it looks like you are the Magento company,and I think you copied from this link https://medium.com/@soni.manthan0/ups-api-get-estimated-delivery-date-456f00e70742, so at least mention the author or link for authenticate, I advice you do not copy, thank you for your answer